# Windows 8 blue screen with DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL Asus.tp

Tags: windows-8, bsod

**First,** I looked at the **Windows Action Center** and followed its instructions.

[image: Windows Action Center]

That means I downloaded `AsusTP_v2.1.4_20130429_normal1.exe` from the ASUS website and ran it. It gave me an error message.

[image: Error Message]

So, I went to Add/Remove Programs and removed two programs that seemed similar to the `AsusTP_v2.1.4_20130429_normal1.exe` that I just downloaded.

[image: Add/Remove Programs]

Then I ran `AsusTP_v2.1.4_20130429_normal1.exe`. **This time it worked.**

**Questions**

- How do I know whether this will prevent further DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL errors?
- My steps were just a guess. What is a more specific way of diagnosing?
- Do I need to look in the Event Viewer?
- Do I need to do a memory dump?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: BlueScreenViewer will tell you all the drivers loaded into memory when the crash happens.  The error itself tells you what driver caused the BSOD.  Windows detected that the problem that caused the BSOD had been resolved by installing an updated version of the driver.  What guessing was involved?

Comment: upload the folder C:\Windows\Minidump (copy it to desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to a cloud service and lost a link here)

Comment: @Ramhound I needed to guess what the error was telling me, because I lack experience in Windows trouble shooting. That is, I didn't know that it displayed the driver that caused the problem. Also, I don't know how you know that Windows detected the problem is resolved. What leads you to that conclusion? Question: Is this http://download.cnet.com/BlueScreenView/3000-2094_4-10965136.html the BlueScreenView to which you were referring? It seems helpful.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the tip. That is useful.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I have garnered these blue screen troubleshooting tips:

1. The blue screen will show you the driver that caused the problem.

   - Write down everything that you see on the blue screen.
   - Then search Google and elsewhere for the terms.
2. C:\Windows\Minidump contains something helpful.

   - TODO: What is in a minidump
   - TODO: How do we use them for troubleshooting?
3. [BlueScreenView](http://download.cnet.com/BlueScreenView/3000-2094_4-10965136.html) will help by showing drivers that were loaded into memory when the crash happened.

   - TODO: How do we use this program?
   - TODO: What are the steps for troubleshooting?
4. [Windows Action Center](http://www.7tutorials.com/introducing-windows-8-how-use-action-center-keep-your-system-secure) will suggest driver fixes that might help.

   - TODO: Add a screen shot of using Windows Action Center.

Comment: 3.) analyze them with WinDbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks